# Sleep() Timeout

Tags: php

I have an issue with my host setting in terms of timeout but actually i don't know which one exactly is responsible for that. When i run this code in php page:

`<?PHP
sleep(30);
echo "Done";
?>`

It gives me `"tcp error operation timeout"`.

But when i change it to be `sleep(20)` it runs successfully. So please help me to find out which item in my php ini file is responsible for this timeout. However i tried to google it and already tried a lot of suggestions but with no luck, and finally i am stuck at this point to let my php script go live.

Comment: May be you should try to change the time limit of the script `void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` which is default to 30 s if i'm not wrong

Comment: Try increasing timeout with set_time_limit()

Comment: I don't think that's PHP's time limit that is being reached. For one thing, unless you are on a Windows host, it only measures when PHP is actively executing, which I'm pretty sure `sleep` will not contribute to. Secondly, that's not the error message it gives.

Comment: the error is as follows: 
    `Network Error (tcp_error)

    A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
    The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

    For assistance, contact your network support team`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, I suspect that this is not PHP timing out, but the actual web server "pulling the plug" (although 30 seconds is a ridiculously short time limit for that).

That is certainly not the normal PHP error message, and you shouldn't be able to induce a PHP timeout using `sleep`, since that uses up no actual CPU time.

Without knowing what kind of host you're running under (Apache? Nginx? IIS? Shared hosting? A VPS? etc) it's hard to know where, and even if, you could change this.

Comment: My hosting settings shows this: `Hosting OS => Proprietary *nix`

Comment: @user2151383 It might be worth asking whoever is running your hosting about this.

Comment: hence there is nothing to do with my php ini file any more ??!!

Comment: @user2151383 I don't think this has anything to do with PHP, so no.

Comment: the error is as follows: `Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out" The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time. For assistance, contact your network support team`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your time limit in your configuration.

You can modifiy the time limit of the script with this line of code:

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

The default value id `30s`. If you are using the set_time_limit() without parameter inside, it will just reset the counter, and the total time available will be increased by 30s.

Take a look at the documentation [set_time_limit documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: I found only 3 items which are handling the timeout issue on my server<br />`default_socket_timeout = 60`, `mysql.connect_timeout = 10` and `pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30` and found also this pice of config `;disable_functions =*****, set_time_limit,******`

Comment: @user2151383 None of those are to do with how long your script takes to run - mysql is a database, a "socket" is something you use to retrieve data from other scripts, and "pfpro" doesn't even seem to exist any more.

Comment: I have a long php loop script that consumes a lot of time that's why i am caring about the execution time

Comment: @user2151383 I understand that; I was saying that the settings you quoted are not the right ones. If this *was* PHP timing out, the setting in question is called [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). You can use [`phpinfo()`](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) to show all settings currently in effect.

Comment: When i ran phpinfo() i did really found this: `max_execution_time => 30` but it's not found in my php ini file !!

Comment: @IMSoP where can i include **max_execution_time = 30** in my php ini file

Comment: @user2151383 Wherever you want - the order and sections are not important in php.ini. As others have said, you can also try `ini_set()` or `set_time_limit()`, but your host may have disabled some or all of these overrides in a master configuration.

Comment: @IMSoP i tried to push sleep(15) twice in my code but with no luck. but i noticed something weird that whatever the value (more than or equal to 30) that i am assigning to sleep() the page has to be loading for 60 seconds then it prints out Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"

Answer (score 0):

30 seconds is default php timeout, if you need to `sleep(30)` you must increase the timeout, there are 2 ways to change it, from php script.

`set_time_limit ( int $seconds );`

OR

`ini_set('max_execution_time', int $seconds);`

Comment: server is remote/hosting? or local ?

Comment: e.g. try ini_set('max_execution_time', 45); whats the result ??

Comment: it's shared server @ awardspace. I tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); & i tried also writing in my hosting ini file max_execution_time=60 but unfortunately with no luck

Comment: looks like you don't have a permissions to access to that property. try echo ini_get('max_execution_time');  look what prints it before and after your changes.

Comment: it printed out **60** but still have no luck

Comment: Sounds like the setting is taking effect, but not solving the problem. That rather leans towards the possibility that is some other timeout, not PHP, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: i agree with both of you since i tested it simply by starting my stop watch and pressed start and the page was loading till 60 seconds and then it printed out error rather than printing the echo string i wrote

Comment: i tried also `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);
echo ini_get('max_execution_time')."<br />"; 
sleep(15);
echo "Time limit is greater than sleep timeout but it works.";` and it worked as well. it seems that the variables are taking effect but ???? i really don't know

Comment: for your problem solution, have You tried to sleep twice by 15 ? try it, sleep(15);sleep(15);echo "a"; it can be server timeout on sleep for security reasons..

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share this answer with every one who is searching for similar issue. After spending several hours searching for the root cause, finally i found out without changing any piece of code that `Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"` error **`disappeared when i ran my script on another machine`**, hence **`the issue was with either my machine or my internet speed`** really i don't know. Anyway the error might be not found only in code.